# using Networkinformation.Ping in for loop somehow freeze my computer and causing blue screen of death c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, local-network

in weird way , what ever i use this function below

my application freeze and take long time before throwing **blue screen of death**

```
public void getLocalNetworkIpList()
{
   Ping p = new Ping();
   PingReply rep;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
      string ipstring = "192.168.1." + i.ToString();
      rep = p.Send(ipstring);

      if (rep.Status == IPStatus.Success)
      Local_IpAdresses_combobox.Items.Add(ipstring);

      }
}
```

this function is only to provide a list of the ip addresses available in my local network , start from 192.168.1.1 and end with 192.168.1.100

im really confused because it look like a simple loop with some ip address checking and pushing in the combobox

Comment: This is a known problem. It only happens when you have the debugger attached IIRC. Edit: I cant find the link since connect was shutdown...

Comment: @leppie ah so is there is any alternative way ? i just want to provide list of Available ip addresses in local network , ill delivering this project tomorrow so any possible help even if its dirty i appreciate it x) welppppp